# Problema con 'this', objeto y boton. javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una clase que hace una conexion a una api, luego con un boton de busqueda llamo a un metodo de una instancia de esta clase. El problema surge con que en el metodo yo hago referencia con this a un atributos de la clase para armar una url, sin embargo al llamarlo desde el boton, como this como el boton. ¿Alguna manera de solucionar esto? o ¿No debe hacerse de esta manera?

```
 searchByName(){        
        let url = `${this.url}&s=${inputSearch.value}&type=${this.type}`;
        console.log(url);       
        //peticion
        fetch(url)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setTitle();            
            insertCard(response.Search);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));    
    }

const connect = new Conexion();
btnSearch.addEventListener("click", connect.searchByName);
```

Solo dejo el trozo del metodo. Al fin al cabo termino con un error dado que la this.url obviamente es undefined por que toma this del boton y no el atributo del objeto. Lo uso asi porque tengo otros metodos para buscar y como la url es la misma la reciclo.

Comment: Lo solucioné con un funcion intermedia que reciba el evento y ejecute el metodo. Pero no se si esto sea lo mas optimo!

Comment: Pública eso como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso puedes usar un bind, lo que hace es que te crea una nueva función en donde la referencia al `this` la modificas, con eso tu código quedaría así:

```
const connect = new Conexion();
btnSearch.addEventListener("click", searchByName.bind(connect));
```

En este caso en tu función `searchByName` cualquier referencia a `this` es ahora una referencia a la instancia de `connect`

Para más información sobre el bind:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind